# PHP socket will not connect to Java server app

Tags: java, php, sockets

I'm trying to open a socket with PHP and have it connect to a Java application. Everytime I try, it times out. I've used http://canyouseeme.org, so I'm sure that the port is open and the Java app is running. I managed to open a local PHP server, and that was the closest thing I could get the PHP to connect to.

PHP:

```
$port = 8040;
$address = "*removed-ip*";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$connection = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
```

Java:

```
    ServerSocket socket;
    Socket connection;
    socket = new ServerSocket(8040);
    while(done == false) {
        connection = socket.accept();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to get a error message to resolve the problem? Using `socket_last_error()` and `socket_strerror()`. See php documentation for more information: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php)

Comment: Error 110, timed out.

Comment: The current protocol set at `socket_create` is `ip`: `var_dump(getprotobynumber(0));`. Try tcp, like so: `string 'tcp'` or `int 6`: `var_dump(getprotobyname('tcp'));` [Sockets programming in Java: A tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html) Paragraph: TCP/IP and UDP/IP communications.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: And, what's the outcome?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. The issue was actually with the host; it's all good. Thanks for the help.